# understanding max in summation notation

Tags: math

This problem is found in https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1326/C. I don't seem to get the summation notation with max function.
[image: This is a past problem in codeforces.]

Here's an explanation of one of the samples where n = 7 and k = 3. I don't get why the partition value of each is 18. This is my question. How was 18 derived from these?
[image: This is an explanation to a test.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite that core part of a question is not about programming, I'll answer.

The essential part in this is that numbers in brackets mean position of element, not the value. So for case 3 the mapping is:

```
index | value
  1   |   2
  2   |   7
  3   |   3
  4   |   1
  5   |   5
  6   |   4
  7   |   6
```

So for the first partitioning (`{[1,2],[3,5],[6,7]}`) it will divide elements in this partitions: `{{2,7}, {3, 1, 5}, {4, 6}}`. And applying `max` to each subset you'll have:

```
{2, 7} -> 7
{3, 1, 5} -> 5
{4, 6} -> 6

7 + 5 + 6 = 18
```

Comment: ahh. now i get it. the numbers in the brackets are the position and not the value. that's why I didn't get it. thanks.